# Making ip commands persistent

Tags: networking, ip, persistence

I want to use the ip-command to change my network config occasionally. How can I make these commands persist across boots? I am using Kubuntu 19.10...
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for helping!
After some more "digging" I came across the fact that Ubuntu has changed to Netplan for doing network configuration. So - I defined the interface using file 
`/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` . 
Everything is fine now...

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing an example command it's difficult to give an absolute solution, but generally speaking if you want a command to execute for every boot or login, there are locations for said command to live.

For example, you could put a command into your ~/.bashrc for execution each time your user logs into either the system or any terminal session.  To do the same for all users, you could add that command to the /etc/bash.bashrc file instead.

If this is a system-level command (rather than a user-level command) there are different locations which may be more appropriate.

Changing the commands would then be a matter of editing the file(s) where they were stowed.

Comment: A wireless connection is user-specific.  There are conditions where the network configuration would be set per-user.  There are probably conditions we could imagine where it would be per-group.  There is no reason to think it must be set system-wide.  Besides, I certainly allow for that possibility in my response.  Why are you objecting, guntbert?